# How to join in BigQuery SQL based on an IF condition

Tags: google-bigquery, left-join

I have a table where each row is a task with a created_at and a completed_at date.

I want to understand this data not by task but by date.

I need to be able to see the number of tasks on any given day.

The SQL below generates and unnests a date array and joins my data table to that result based on the created_at date, but this won't fit my needs.

```
WITH main FROM (
  SELECT * FROM `data.task_merge`),

second AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM unnest(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-01-01', '2022-12-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS newdate)

SELECT *
FROM second
LEFT JOIN main
ON second.newdate = cast(main.created_at AS DATE)
```

What I need:

For every date x in the date array: If task y in the dataset has a created_at date <= x and a completed_at date >= x, join that task to the table against x. Then increment y+1 and repeat against x, and when we've finished the table of tasks, increment to x+1 and restart at y.

Answer (score 0):

I answered myself - you just put a WHERE in the ON part of the join

Comment: A where clause is not in an on clause, it is after; its input is the result of a preceding a join+on.

Comment: This is a poor answer because it is vague, and answers that are just code are also poor, because an answer should explain why/how its code solves the problem the question is asking about. [answer] [Help]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).